# Limit the number of record in a relation

Tags: ms-access, join

I've a relation `1:M` ina MS Access database. Is there a way to lock the maximum number of records in the `"M"` side of relation? So for any entry in the first A table I could have only a certain number in the `M` table?

[image]

Comment: You can limit number of records in query by `top` keyword.

Comment: Not on the table level. You'll have to enforce that limitation in the form(s) where users add records.